# Inserting code with a keybinding in Visual Studio Code

Tags: key-bindings, visual-studio-code

How can I insert code in Visual Studio Code for MacOS with key bindings? For example in Sublime I can insert a `console.log` like this:

```json
{ 
  "keys": ["super+shift+l"],
  "command": "insert_snippet",
  "args": {
    "contents": "console.log('test:' + varname);${0}"
  }
},
```

If I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> I get `console.log('test:' + varname);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify what the `insertSnippet` command should insert like this:

```json
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
       "snippet": "console.log('test:' + varname);${0}"
    }
}
```